# Keep just duplicate indices after append on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I'm trying to form a time series, and I appended data from a 2014 and a 2015 databases. The thing is, I just need observations where my id is present for both years. I know how to do this on a horizontal merge, but is there a way to do it with append? or else, is there a way to reshape my merged data?

My data looks like this:

`df14` :

```
id year value1 value2
1  2014   a       x
2  2014   b       y
```

`df15`:

```
id year value1 value2
2  2015   c       w
3  2015   d       z
```

In this case, I just want a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
id year value1 value2
2  2015   c       w
2  2014   b       y
```

But `df14.append(df15)` brings a complete append and there's no index match option.

Is there a way to do this? Couldn't find it, even though it should be straightforward.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll probably want to `groupby(id)` and filter based on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `duplicated` with the `keep=False` argument to subset the concatenated `DataFrame`.

```
df = pd.concat([df14, df15], ignore_index=True)
df[df.duplicated('id', keep=False)]
```

Output:

```
   id  year value1 value2
1   2  2014      b      y
2   2  2015      c      w
```

For Wen's point, if there are duplicates in one frame, and you need to only select duplicates across different years, subset with `transform`.

```
df[df.groupby('id').year.transform(lambda x: x.nunique() > 1)]
# or 
df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: x.year.nunique() > 1)
```

Comment: when df14 have duplicate in id itself , the output is not right .

Comment: I guess that's a good point in general. Though since they came from databases, there's a good chance that `id` is the primary key, so it would not be duplicated within each frame.

Comment: That's right, those are unique identifiers, so, at least for my problem, it works like a charm! Thanks ALollz .

Answer (score 2):

1. Set the index to be the `'id'` column for both dataframes
2. Use the `align` method with the `inner` argument
3. Append dataframes and reset the index

---

```
d14, d15 = df14.set_index('id').align(df15.set_index('id'), 'inner')

d14.append(d15).reset_index()

   id  year value1 value2
0   2  2014      b      y
1   2  2015      c      w
```